# How to re-write this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am doing this excercise to practice for an exam. However, I do not know how to get the expected answer. Someone please help me. You can see my summarized working.

[image]

Comment: I see why I would have to divide a polynomial by another of one degree less, yet I do not know how to find both of these polynomials. Ultimately these polynomials is the expression I am looking for.

Comment: You have the answer. What is the confusion? Are you asking why $\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$ should be in the blank?

Comment: I do not know how to find the expression that should go on the red line displayed in "My Work". That expression is  (a^n-1)/a-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a^{n-n}=a^0=1$.

Let $S=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a^{n-(n-1)}+a^{n-n}=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+1$. Then
$$
aS=a^n+a^{n-1}+\cdots +a.
$$
Now
$$
aS-S = a^n-1.
$$
Hence
$$
S=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}.
$$

---

You could try $n=4$ to understand what was going on above.

When $n=4$,
$$
S=a^3+a^2+a+1,\quad aS = a^4+a^3+a^2+a.
$$
Thus
$$
(a-1)S=aS-S = (a^4+a^3+a^2+a)- (a^3+a^2+a+1)=a^4-1.
$$
So
$$
a^3+a^2+a+1=S=\frac{a^4-1}{a-1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You're right that
\begin{equation}
f^n(x) = a^nx + (a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} + \dots + a + 1)b
\end{equation}
We can write this more compactly as as
\begin{equation}
f^n(x) = a^n x + \left( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a^j \right)b
\end{equation} 
The term in brackets is a [Geometric Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). Hence, it can be calculated by the formula
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a^j = \dfrac{a^{(n-1)+1} -1}{a-1} = \dfrac{a^n - 1}{a-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, try to check it inductively. By the way, the assumption $-1<a<1$ guerantees the convergence of the geometric series $1+a+a^2+\dots$, so it i
is not necessary here, the argument works for all $a\ne 1$. If $a=1$, then $f(x)=x+b$ and $f^n(x)=x+nb$.